# Loading .png file for use as a sprite in Python Arcade

Tags: python, arcade

I am trying to create a Player class in Python Arcade wherein I use a .png image of a rectangle to create a sprite which the user moves in order to hit a ball. However, whenever I run the program, I receive a "FileNotFoundError". The file name is Red_Rectangle.png and it is currently located on my desktop. Below is an excerpt of the code that I am using. The error is triggered in the line containing "Red_Rectangle.png".

```
def MyGame(arcade.Window):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__(width, height)
        self.player_list = None
        self.player_sprite = None
        self.score = 0

        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.BLACK)

    def setup(self):
        self.player_list = arcade.SpriteList()

        self.score = 0
        self.player_sprite = Player("Red_Rectangle.png", SPRITE_SCALING)
        self.player_sprite.center_x = 50
        self.player_sprite.center_y = 50
        self.player_list.append(self.player_sprite)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because if you do a [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) it will not return that the image is there, when Player method would want 'E:/somedir/Red_Rectangle.png' because the file does not exist in the current directory.

Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to prepend the directory to your filename:

```
import os
path = r'E:/somedir'
def MyGame(arcade.Window):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__(width, height)
        self.player_list = None
        self.player_sprite = None
        self.score =0
        arcade.set_background_color (arcade.color.BLACK)

    def setup(self):
        self.player_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.score = 0
        self.player_sprite = Player(os.path.join(path, "Red_Rectangle.png"), SPRITE_SCALING)
        self.player_sprite.center_x = 50
        self.player_sprite.center_y = 50
        self.player_list.append (self.player_sprite)
```

Or simply place the image file in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

From information you have given, it seem file is not found, because it is not in working directory.

If you want to load image file from desktop, you need to specify path to desktop:

```
import os

...

self.player_sprite = Player(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Red_Rectangle.png"), SPRITE_SCALING)
```

Or move image file to your working directory.