# How to deal with texture set problem with Python,I can't create sprite

Tags: python-3.x, sprite, texture-mapping, texturepacker, arcade

It show an error when I run my program which said I attempted to draw a sprite without a texture set,please help,great thanks

Comment: This is common error when the required image does not exist in the expected location.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201693/loading-png-file-for-use-as-a-sprite-in-python-arcade

Comment: Please show your code